# Camera settings to imitate Samsung Note 9

Tags: camera, properties

Hello stackexchange community

I wish you all a happy holiday season

I would like to know what values , for my mobile phone "Samsung Note 9", i must set in Blender 2.8

**Specifications** i know

**Sensor Size:** 1/2.55; **Wide angle:** 26mm; **Sensor ratio:** 4:3; **field of view:** 77°

the Crop factor I don't know

**My settings:**

for lens:
**Type:** Pespective; **Focal Length**: 26mm;

for camera: **Sensor Fit:** Auto; **Sensor Width:** 26mm;

*(Here I have my problems, If i choose 4:3 inches, then the frame is too small.)*

Which settings are still necessary or have to be set exactly to simulate the camera?

*Thank you for your answers in advance*

CloneBorg

Comment: 4:3 is the aspect ratio so not about inches buddy. Best way is to take a picture of something pretty simple, replicate it in Blender, set the camera and "get rid" of all the differences. Also the focal of 26mm seems to be not right as a perspective settings of Samsung.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. 1. I put a box right in front of the camera, so that the right and left sides fit exactly into the picture from the Kamera (Display).
2. Then I measured the distance from the camera to the carton.
3. In Blender I adopted exactly the measurements of the cardboard and the distance of the camera.
4. I set the focal lens to 26mm.
5. Then I used the slider from the sensor width, until the box fits into the frame from the camera picture.

Now I've come close to what I wanted.

Comment: Happy to hear that Buddy ;).